# Android - Best practice to pass objects between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

My scenario is like this:
I have a one activity architecture of my app, and I have multiple fragments, which I navigate to using the `NavController` object.

In my `MainActivity` I create an object called `Orchestrator` which I want to create just once, and use all over the app and fragments.
The `Orchestrator` also holds the `context` of the `MainActivity`.

I currently pass the object between the app by createing an interface called `IShared` look like this:

```
interface IShared {
    Orchestrator getOrchestrator();
}
```

The `MainActivity` implements this interface so it looks something like this:

```
public activity MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IShared {

    private Orchestrator orchestrator;
    
    @Override
    public onCreate() {
        ...
        orchestrator = new Orchestrator(requireContext());
        ...
    }
    
    @override
    public Orchestrator getOrchestrator() {
        return orchestrator;
    }

}
```

and I get the `Orchestrator` object in the fragment through the `onAttach` method:

```
private Orchestrator orchestrator;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    orchestrator = ((Orchestrator1) context).getOrchestrator()
}
```

but my problem is that the `onAttach` method is deprecated, so I guess this is not the best practice of doing this.

What should I do then?
Should I use a `ViewModel` that will hold the `orchestrator` even though it is not a UI object? it is an object which holds a lot of data that I need to pass between fragments and some of the fragments also changes the data of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the recommended practices.

Various ideas.

1. Yes, use view models.
2. Use Dependency Injection (like Hilt) or any of the alternatives (Koin, Dagger, etc.)
3. I don't know what your *orchestrator* does, but I don't think it's the Activity's responsibility to create such an important object that you want shared across instances of UI. Feels like there's got to be a Factory/Repository where this object comes from, and that each viewModel can pick from.

Do not fight the Framework, and don't couple *all* your fragments with an interface like that. Either inject it directly in the fragments via DependencyInjection, or *observe* the object through a viewmodel (shared?) and or individual viewModels for each Fragment/Screen. Or Both, you can have a shared viewmodel (provided by the activity) in addition to individual view models for each fragment.

> even though it is not a UI object?

If it's not a UI object, then why is it in the UI to begin with?

#### UPDATE

> it's in the UI because some buttons in the UI, changes some of the fields inside the object. for example pressing the "connect" button in the UI, changes the "connected" boolean variable in the orchestrator to true. How can I create this object and add a context to if, if not from the MainActivity?

If pressing a button changes the state of the object, then the correct flow would be:

1. User taps UI "view".
2. Fragment forwards action to the ViewModel.
3. ViewModel decides what happens (in this case, the connected button was pressed, so it informs the UseCase/Interactor that knows what to do when the connect button is pressed).
4. UseCase/Interactor does what it needs. In this case, updates or returns a new Orchestrator with the state changed (connected = true). If you're using coroutines, this is potentially a `suspend` function as well (probably not to just update a boolean... but if you needed to do more than that, then probably yes).
5. ViewModel, which called `val newOrch = connectedUseCase.onConnected()` (for e.g. **remember this is pseudo-code**, there are multiple ways to do this), now *emits* the new `Orchestrator` it just received to a `flow` `StateFlow` or `SharedFlow` (or even `LiveData` if you use that, I wouldn't since StateFlow is better most of the times).
6. Fragment or Activity that initiated this, was observing its state from the ViewModel all the time and will `collect` the new State and react to it (say, for e.g. by changing a text from `not connected` to `connected`.

Now you'd argue this is a lot of overhead for a "simple boolean change" and I'd somewhat agree that indeed it is, but such is the complexity of a modern, decoupled application.

The benefits are mid-long term, as you'd now no longer need to worry about this operation (the Usecase can be reused) and the Activity/Fragment no longer really know much (nor maintain) their "common Orchestrator".

All these concepts are better explained and expanded in the [Guide to Android Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture) official website.

As for the final bit of your question:

> How can I create this object and add a context to if, if not from the MainActivity?

If this object must exist from the beginning of your app, then your ViewModel#init() (for your activity) could call a UseCase or create it itself. You say it's not a UI object, but it has UI **STATE** in it, so someone must create it, set the initial state, and hold a reference to it. Either have an Orchestrator "Repository" or "factory" or "OrchestratorInitUseCase" that creates it for you.

You do *not* need (and should not) have a `Context` Stored in any of these things. You only need the `Context` to perform Android Framework operations (theme, navigation, etc.) and these can happen in the Fragment/Activity that triggers the action/event once the ViewModel they are observing emits the corresponding value(s). There's no need to send the context anywhere.

Comment: it's in the UI because some buttons in the UI, changes some of the fields inside the object. for example pressing the "connect" button in the UI, changes the "connected" boolean variable in the `orchestrator` to true. How can I create this object and add a `context` to if, if not from the `MainActivity`? thanks!

Comment: If I will create a ViewModel, then I need to obtain it in the fragment like so: `ViewModelProvider(getActivity())...` which may produce a NPE in the fragment, I wanted to avoid this, is it possible? and, you think the ViewModel is a better option than Dependency Injection? if so ,why? BTW I'm using java, not kotlin.

Comment: I think you should consider asking another question if you're unsure about viewModel usage. Unless you're using a headless fragment (which seems like you aren't), you should use `ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()` and yes, it will crash if there's no activity, but that would be a bug on your end. If you're using "modern" versions of the dependencies, this is guaranteed to work fine provided you're not doing anything strange. As for Java vs. Kotlin, in general, short of syntax differences, most if not all things done in KT have a java equivalent (sometimes a bit more verbose).

Comment: "ViewModel is a better option than Dependency Injection?" They are not exclusive. You should inject the ViewModel dependencies using DI as well. And you may as well inject the viewModels in the activity/fragments... so you wouldn't even need to use the ViewModelProvider. Take a look at [the Hilt](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack) guide as an example.

Comment: thank you, you gave me a lot to think about and redesign my app. thanks a lot.

Comment: can I use StateFlow in java? from what I red a bit, I see I can only use LiveData if my app is already written in Java

Comment: Great question, I honestly don't know. I'd think it's possible, as it's all ultimately Java Bytecode, *but*, there may be a lot of inconveniences when using Java. I haven't written pure Java since 2018 I think (short of maintaining existing classes), so I really don't know what the limitations of Java are these days. YOu can always mix Java with some Kotlin if you need to (or write abstractions around it) but other than that, I don't have a valid answer for you as I haven't experimented with that scenario. When in doubt, use LiveData.

Comment: as I'm still struggling on refactoring my app, I am facing another issue: I need to read files in some cases, and I do not want to do that in the fragment or activity (I assume) and inorder to read the files, I must pass the `context` object to deeper classes: `context.openFileInput(...)`. but I guess it's a bad practice to pass the `context` outside the activity/fragment as you mentioned. is there a better way doing so? inject the context to the deeper classes maybe?

Comment: If you need to pass a context, pass the static application context. If you're in a fragment, you can use something like         `requireActivity().getApplicationContext()` to your use-case/code where you open the file input. You can (and probably should) inject this context directly from your Dependency Injection framework. Just make sure it's the static application context and not an activity/fragment (or view) which could act as a context as well.